# what should i do if i get error firebase client authorization?

Tags: java, android, firebase, api, authentication

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
```

E/FirebaseAuth: [GetAuthDomainTask] Error getting project config. Failed with

```
"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_CERT_HASH : Client does not match API key",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "INVALID_CERT_HASH : Client does not match API key",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
 400
```

i have tried to send OTP to user via sms. with firebase API and i get this error in logs. I have checked API key in google services.json file they are all correct. i don't know what to do?   Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the SHA1 , when using Verification OTP you ll have to provide the SHA1 key , so get the SHA1 key ,copy paste in in your firebase console settings

Project Settings -> General -> Scroll down and click add print -> put your SHA1 key

Comment: That's my pleasure , if you found the answer helpful please upvote so it is helpful for someone else thank you

Comment: i have upvoted but stack overflow is not displaying upvote if you have reputation  less than 15.

Comment: In my own case I have added both Sha1 and Sha256 but I am still getting the same error. I have created the project on Firebase and downloaded the google-service.json file from the new Firebase Project but the app still allows me to login using old credentials, but does not allow me to register new user.

Comment: @Dangdat Sometimes I make some same mistake with firebase token, authentication. But not like you. Try clearing the PlayStore app cache, then try again.